# How to count one column when another column is distinct (Oracle BIEE)

Tags: obiee

I want to have a new column showing how many orders that I have for the shipment.

How can I do that in obiee

Example Table:

| Shipment | Order | Order Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 001 | 3 |
| 125 | 002 | 3 |
| 125 | 003 | 3 |
| 126 | 004 | 2 |
| 126 | 005 | 2 |

I can't have a new column with order quantity for each shipment

Answer (score 0):

Add a sum for the "Shipment" attribute to the visualization and the tool does it automatically. Or create a measure using SUM("Order Quantity" by "Shipment") which you can then use to cross-calculate